# Generating and serving XML files on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, playframework-1.x

I'm using play framework 1.2.4 and deploying my application on GAE.

I'm trying to get data from datastore and create a XML file based on that data.
Then, I have javascript that use this file to populate a google map. (the XML file has latitude and longitude).

Once, deploying the application it's not working 'cause I can't write/create a file on the server.

I've tried before to work with JSON object instead of XML but it didn't work.

Is there any way that I can resolve this and work with a XML file?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to create an actual file? And why would JSON vs XML make a difference?

Just write a handler which queries the datastore returns the data directly, in whichever format you need.

Comment: Thanks sir for answering, my issue is that I'm not used to javascript so I'm always getting troubles working with it.
And also passing variables from controller to javascript in view (with playframework) it doesn't work.
That's why I thought working with JSON or XML.

Comment: I don't see how your comment contradicts my answer at all. Your handler should return JSON or XML dynamically, rather than writing it to a file.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I think I misunderstood your answer. Please explain how can I re write my code in order to return it dynamically ? If you have any links that could help me